# mysql order by in view is discarded when outer query has where clause

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have a view `v1` with an `ORDER BY` clause that is ignored when a:

```
SELECT * FROM v1 WHERE <clause>
```

is run on that view; but if that statement loses the `WHERE` clause, then the ordering is preserved.

I searched the documentation but I found no reference except this (from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html)):

> If ORDER BY occurs within a subquery and also is applied in the outer query, the outermost ORDER BY takes precedence.

I tried specifying all the available `ALGORITHM` options, but I get the same result.

Is there something I am missing, or is it expected that inner ORDER BY are discarded?

## UPDATE

It seems that's not an issue with the view, since I get the same behaviour if, given:

- `s1 := SELECT ... FROM ... ORDER BY ...`
- `CREATE VIEW v1 AS <s1>`

I run the query:

```
SELECT * FROM ( <s1> ) WHERE ...
```

The same "reordering" appears. Though I'm not sure, this seems related to [this bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69670).

Comment: If there is no ORDER BY clause in the external query, the order of records returned is random, and the sorting in the subquery or view is ignored. If the records are returned in the same order that is specified in the subquery or view, it is simply an accident.

Comment: What Akina says comes from the SQL standard, and did not use to be the case in MySQL or MariaDB.